# How do I parallelize for-loop in octave using pararrayfun (or any other function will also do)?

Tags: parallel-processing, octave

Well, I'm new to octave and i wanted to know how to implement parallel execution of for loop in octave.

I'm looking for parallel implementation of the below code (its not the exact code that I'm trying to execute, but something similar to this)

```
`%read a csv file
 master_sheet = csv2cell('master_sheet.csv');

 delta = 0.001;
 nprocs= nproc();

%extract some values from the csv file and store it in the variables
a =  master_sheet{34,2} ;
b =  master_sheet{38,2} ;
c =  master_sheet{39,2} ;


for i=0:1000
  %%create variants of a,b and c by adding a delta value
   a_adj = a +(i)*delta ;
   b_adj = b +(i)*delta ;
   c_adj = c +(i)*delta ;

 %club all the above variables and put it to an array variable
 array_abc = [a_adj, b_adj, c_adj];

 %send this array as an argument/parameter to a function
 %processingData() function would essentially perform some series of calculation and would write the 
 %results onto a file   
 processingData(array_abc);
 endfor
```

Currently, I'm using parallel pkg (pararrayfun) to implement this, but if there is any other way(package) that could achieve the parallelization of for loop in octave, then I'm open to exploring that as well.

Thank you!

Comment: The 'official' solution is the parallel pkg, as you mentioned. Why is that not working for you?

Comment: @tpapastylianou, sorry for the delayed response. I ran into the below issue when implementing the parcellfun() function from parallel package.  error: parcellfun: fun must be either a function handle or name.

Comment: this is how I called the parcellfun function                                          `parcellfun(nprocs, @processingData(array_abc),array_abc, delta_avg)`                                             __//here the array_abc is input array and delta_avg is the output array__                                          
                                                                                                                             
I suppose, I'm getting the syntax wrong; If you could help me figure this out, that'd be helpful.

Comment: well, there's no point providing this as an actual answer here, since it is not the actual question being asked in the post, but yes, effectively you're using the function wrong. The `@processingData(array_abd)` is not what this function expects. You should be passing in a function handle, or an appropriate anonymous function which handles your input.